# How to scan a string in R

Tags: r

This is just basic arithmetic and conditional work in R, no file included
Here's the code

```
val <- scan()
repeat{
type <- scan()
if (type=="luxe"|"normal")
break
}
if (type=="LUXE"){
price <- val + (val * 0.2)
} else {
price <- val + (val * 0.1)
}
print(price)
```

I want to scan an article's price and type in order to give the taxed price, but the console keeps returning "scan expected a real, got 'luxe'"

Comment: `scan()` is designed to read numbers from the console.  When you run the first line `val <- scan()`, it will expect the second line to be the numbers, so it dies with `Error in scan() : scan() expected 'a real', got 'repeat{'`.   You seem to be expecting it to do something completely different, like scanning a bar code or QR code.

Comment: See `help("scan")`and in particular the documentation of the `what` parameter.

Comment: It's not actually a qr code @user2554330 we're on our first steps at the university in R and the task is that user gives a price of a product and its type, to know if its tax is 10 or 20 percent (luxe, normal in the code) and then calculate its taxed price